# LinkedIn Connections API docs

Tags: linkedin-api

I've looked at all the questions and replies here and also applied for a partner account as the LinkedIn docs are so confusing now.

Where do I go to read about how to connect my API to give access to your or anyone's LinkedIn connections? I'd like to retrieve all a persons contact details and their connections details for populating an address book.

I got declined with no helpful info or pointers and getting in contact with LinkedIn is just as hard:

> Dear developer,
>
> Thanks for submitting your request for enhanced API access through the LinkedIn developer site. We reviewed the information provided in your application and determined that your use case does not qualify for enhanced API access.
>
> Due to the high volume of requests we receive, we unfortunately cannot provide detailed feedback about your individual application. If you have further questions about the use cases we support through our Open APIs, please review our developer site (https://developer.linkedin.com/) and API Terms of Use (https://developer.linkedin.com/legal/api-terms-of-use).
>
> Thanks for being part of our developer community.
>
> The LinkedIn Business Development Team
>
> [Please do not reply to this email]

Comment: Yeah, this sucks. What the hell LinkedIn.